# Twig_Error_Loader directory does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I want to change render path of twig. I am using twig with codeigniter. my code is below:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(FCPATH.'themes/site/default');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->load('layout.twig.php');
echo $twig->render(APPPATH.'views/site/welcome.twig.php', $data);
```

But code is giving error:

```
Type: Twig_Error_Loader

Message: Unable to find template "/var/www/html/test.ab/application/views/site/welcome.twig.php" (looked into: /var/www/html/test.ab/themes/site/default).

Filename: /var/www/html/test.ab/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php

Line Number: 232
```

Comment: Why do you set tags as symfony while you are using CI.... ?

Comment: I thought, twig is developed by symphony so may be I get help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(FCPATH.'themes/site/default');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
echo $twig->render('welcome.twig.php', $data);`

the view file is relative to FCPATH.'themes/site/default'